# How to append a path to PHP's include_path in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, include-path

Currently on my site I'm using statements like:

```
include 'head.php';
include '../head.php';
include '../../head.php';
```

depending on how many nested folders deep I am. I'm sure there is a better way to do this.

I'm convinced `.htaccess` is the solution, but I'm not sure how to go about implementing it. If I insert:

```
php_value include_path "public/html/root"
```

... I lose the rest of my paths (`/usr/lib/php`, etc). I naively tried:

```
php_value include_path $include_path . "(path)"
```

but of course this didn't work.  How could I prepend or append a single path to this list with `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you can't edit the `php.ini` file itself, you could add

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path_to_add);
```

before your `include` statements.

However if you find yourself having `include` or `require` troubles, it is probably a code smell. The best solution would be a good object-oriented design with a good `__autoload` function.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on a server with a lot of other sites right now... I don't want to put the path_to_add in every single file because it's something odd like /home/12345678/public_html... I'd just like to add the "public_html" to the include path in the simplest way possible. Doing a search and replace when the site gets transferred seems clunky.

Comment: Could you look up the current php `include_path` with `php_info()` or `get_include_path()` and then add
    php_value include_path "public/html/root:/first/old/path:/second/old/path"
to your `.htaccess`. You'd only have to do it once.

Comment: True, but I was hoping for a more elegant solution. Hopefully they don't reconfigure the server any time soon. Anyways thanks for the help, this is probably the best it can get.

Answer (score 28):

Create in the sub-sub-directories a file `.htaccess` with the contents

```
php_value include_path '../../includes'
```

or whatever `include_path` is right for that directory.

Advantages:

1. No ugly hack with multiple includes with different depth. Just `include 'head.php'`.
2. No dependency on editing `php.ini`.
3. No need to use `set_include_path()` before including.
4. No dependency on including constants like `include INCLUDE_PATH . 'head.php'`.

Price to pay:

You litter your sub-sub-directories each with a file `.htaccess`.

Comment: I like it, and appreciate the writeup with clearly articulated benefit & cost. I dont like the littering, but I'm doing it. Thanks! :)

Comment: I very much like this method because a) it decouples my application's configuration from my application's logic (no `set_include_path()` calls), yet my application's configuration remains within my application and b) it decouples my application's configuration from my application environment (no changes to `php.ini` or `httpd.conf` or whatever). Sure, you'll "suffer" from an extra read operation per directory per web request, but so what? A moderately-sized PHP app is going to have dozens or more PHP includes on each request anyway, unless it's deployed to prod via something like ScriptJoiner.

Comment: This rule is not append but removes all previously defined include paths. But how to append new paths with .htaccess?

Comment: Good question. I don't know.