# Is it possible to set include_path without using php.ini or .htaccess, affecting all PHP directories?

Tags: php, include-path

On my localhost, I tinker with php.ini to set the include_path. But, overtime the line for the include_path in my php.ini has grown and it looks, ummm, unsightly. I'm looking for a way to set include_path like, I can copy-paste a single include line, say `<?php include("superfile.php");?>` on all pages, regardless of where they are in the directory tree, where superfile contains all include_path directives.

I've already tried,

```
<?php
    $include_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/more/directories/as/needed/";
    ini_set("include_path", $include_path);
    include("initialize.php");
?>
```

and saved it on the root folder as `superfile.php`. However if I want to set the include path of a file residing at, say root/sub, by way of `superfile.php` I need to do `<?php include("../superfile.php"); ?>` (with "directory up" dots), defeating my purpose of setting the include_path.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: If your file at root/sub has the include_path set, include 'superfile.php' will work, I don't catch your drift here mate.

Comment: My bad. I phrased my question badly, sorry. Edited it now to be (hopefully) clearer.

Comment: This question has been answered wrongly. **No, it is not possible at all!** You must edit `php.ini` to set `include_path` for all directories. An alternative is placing a `.htaccess` file in all directories as outlined in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8579545/220060, but a **single** file does not suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've removed all of your custom `include_path` directives from the php.ini.

To allow all scripts to call `<?php include("superfile.php");?>` simply add the one entry to your php.ini `include_path` that will allow this, and your set.

Comment: Errr...no, sorry. Bad tenses and phrasing on my part so my question is, admittedly, vague and unclear. I've edited it and I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: @skytreader `superfile.php` can only have influence over files that include it, and in order to include it, files need to know where it is relative to themselves OR via htaccess/php.ini include_path settings.